# .htaccess to add dynamic url segments to an existing rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have this rule in place

```
# Rewrite for account view
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?type=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]
```

which translate to `http://www.site.com/user/s2xi`

but now I want to get even more creative with the url and append a theme location to it so:

```
http://www.site.com/user/s2xi/theme/slate/
```

so that I can for instance access the CSS file for the theme I would simply need to type in

```
http://www.site.com/user/s2xi/theme/slate/css/slate.css
```

how can I modify or add another RewriteRule to be able to get the results I want?

also, how would I be able to apply and access my theme files with the new url in my PHP code?

my current path to my themes is `library/themes/users/slate` with sub folders `/css` and `/js`

My attempt:

```
# Rewrite for user theme location
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/theme/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?type=$1&user=$2$theme=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest redirecting all requests to one file, e.g. `index.php` and then get the url by using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. You can then use this data and for example explode it. Then you will be able to dynamically determine which page will be loaded.

You can use the following code to redirect all requests to `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

You could also exclude particular filetypes from being redirected to this PHP file. For example static content like CSS, JavaScript etc. The following code will, for example, exclude all files with a CSS, JS, PNG or JPG extension:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !\.(css|js|png|jpg)$ index.php
```

To exclude all files that do exist, you could use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: hmmm I'm using a smarty template so I assign paths to my css and js and images in a variable. I then do something like `<link href="http://www.site.com/{$theme_css}" />` which should look like `<link href="http://www.site.com/user/s2xi/theme/slate/css/slate.css" />` which would point to `<link href="http://www.site.com/library/themes/users/slate/css/slate.css" />` so I dunno how to go about assigning the correct path based off the url

Comment: @s2xi: Well, if you redirect all requests to `index.php` and you are navigating to the URL `http://www.site.com/user/s2xi/theme/slate/css/slate.css`, then the index file will be loaded. In this file you could put the requested URL into a variable and determine which file will be loaded. And if you explode the URL on the slashes, you would get all the parameters. So you could make conditions like `if($params[0] == 'user')` etcetera.

Comment: hmmm, one thing was i didn't want to loose the `http://www.site.com/user/s2xi` in the url bar but then reference the new url in my html code when i'm including the css and js files

Comment: @s2xi: Once you are in PHP, you can do so many things with the requests. You could make another if statement or you could just exclude the CSS filetype from the redirect, so you would be able to navigate to the file using either PHP or the original URL. You could also use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f ` to exclude all files that do exist. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can put rest of the path into third get parametar:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ account.php?type=$1&user=$2&rest_of_the_url=$3 [NC,L]
```

[EDIT]

Ok, for you case I think you should write .htaccess redirect so for css and js file apache goes directly to them. Because php processing would be unnecessary overhead, unless you want to check user credentials or something like that.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/theme/([^/]+)/(.+\.(?:css|js|png|jpg))$ /library/themes/users/$3/$4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I thought about that and made this [I added it to my post]

Comment: My problem at 2:42am is that I can't wrap my head around how I can add the rule, and apply it in my php code (or html code) to point to my theme and theme files like file.css and file.js