# RewriteRule Page + Category Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, include

I have the following .htaccess rewriting urls such as url.com/category/page and url.com/page and then the PHP to set the variables from the $_GET's.

The issue is that the page category.php will work with just url.com/category but then when i want to go url.com/category/page it fails because the file category.php AND folder category need to exists and because the folder exists it does not work... i am unsure if this makes sense but i am really failing to see a way around this..

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?category=$1&page=$2   [L]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  index.php?page=$1    [L]
```

PHP

```
$url = '';
if (!empty($_GET['category'])) {
    $url .= $_GET['category'] . '/';
}
if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $url .= $_GET['page'] . '.php';
} else {
    $url .= "pages/home.php";
}
include $url;
```

Comment: Just a side note that the PHP code you've posted isn't very secure, though perhaps this is just to keep the example simple. Make sure you have code that prevents ../ directory traversal to open .php files you weren't intending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a condition in your code which will redirect the browser to the folder it it exists 

(`RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d`). If you remove this, it should be working.

If you would like to redirect it conditionally to a folder if it exists, you could adjust it using if statements in PHP.

Comment: If i disable those lines and go to url.com/category (i have category.php and a folder category) it redirects to url.com/category/?page=category and fails obviously.

Comment: You could remove those conditions altogether and redirect all requests to `index.php`. Once you are in PHP you could easily control the requests. I have posted a more detailed explaination to another question like this before. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323224/htaccess-to-add-dynamic-url-segments-to-an-existing-rewrite-rule/5323288#5323288

Comment: @medoix: Allright, I understand. Well, if the `RewriteCond` condition is matched, the `RewriteRule` will not be used. So practically if the directory `category` exists, it will not send the request to `index.php`. The easiest solution would be to change the directory name.

Comment: I know that would be the simplest solution, but as you can see in the PHP ($url .= $_GET['category'] . '/';) it sets the path depending on the URL. So how would i still keep the URL as /category/page but the folder as category_f/page for example?

Comment: I think i answered my own question, i just set the above mentioned line to ($url .= $_GET['category'] . '_f/';) and changed the folder name to category_f and it works.