# I want to change my url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i can change my url in simple form.
how can i use rewrite rule in htaccess

my url is http://test.com/wishdetails?wishid=czoyOiIzNiI7&title=my_weekend_story

i want this http://test.com/wishdetails/my_weekend_story

so please help me. how can i change 
please do reply fast.

Thanks....................

Comment: Where is this "wishid" supposed to come from?

Comment: There are thousands of similar questions already answered.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wishdetails/my_weekend_story$ wishdetails?wishid=czoyOiIzNiI7&title=my_weekend_story
```

Or if `my_weekend_story` is variable, you could use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wishdetails/(\w+)$ wishdetails?wishid=czoyOiIzNiI7&title=$1
```

Please do note that you will need to have enabled mod_rewrite if you are using Apache.

Comment: Seems like whatever takes the place of 'my_weekend_story' should be the value for `title` in the query string.

Comment: Can we create dynamic rule for dynamically created pages also

Comment: @Starx: Yes that is possible. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323224/htaccess-to-add-dynamic-url-segments-to-an-existing-rewrite-rule/5323288#5323288

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wishdetails/([^/]*)$ /wishdetails?wishid=czoyOiIzNiI7&title=$1 [L]
```