# Need help with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1 [L,QSA]

index.php?action=product shop.com/product
index.php?action=product/add shop.com/product/add
```

Now I want to add paging to some of the pages, something like

```
index.php?action=product&page=1&show=20 shop.com/product/1/20
index.php?action=product/add&page=1&show=20 shop.com/product/add/1/20
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Pagination is generally done by regular get parameters - `shop.com/product?page=42`. There is no any reason to want to move everything to be handled by mod_rewrite. As for me `product/1/20` says nothing, whereas `product?page=1&show=20` is very self-descriptive url.

Comment: Mod_rewrite has nothing to do with PHP, just saying.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product$ index.php?action=product
RewriteRule ^product/add$ index.php?action=product/add
RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)/(\d+)$ index.php?action=product&page=$1&show=$2
RewriteRule ^product/add/(\d+)/(\d+)$ index.php?action=product/add&page=$1&show=$2
```

I suggest taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323224/htaccess-to-add-dynamic-url-segments-to-an-existing-rewrite-rule/5323288#5323288) too. I think it would be better in this case.

Comment: wow thank you for the replay but i can't do this for every file i have 5-10 various actions this means i'll have to write more than 10 RewriteRules for every file.. also if add new action i my code i'll have to add a RewriteRule for it and this doesn't look very flexible for me
p.s. sorry for my english ^^

Comment: @Stasa: I know that this is not very flexible. That is why I have also added the link to the answer.